# Calculation sum rows below in R based on one value

Tags: r, sum, rows

I have a database as displayed, and would like to calculate the sum of the rows below based on one value in one column.

For example:

- if the "safety stock = 2 months", the calculated safety stocks in units is the sum of 2 rows below, for the same product
- if the "safety stock = 3 months", the calculated safety stocks in units is the sum of 3 rows below, for the same product

Would anybody know how to proceed in R?

[image: Calculation Sum Rows Below in R]

Comment: Please add a reproducible example so that others can help you. For example you can use R's `dput()` function to export data as text and add it your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 'Safety_Stocks' is a single value for each 'Product', we can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Product', get the `lead` values with `shift` by specifying the 'n' as the sequence of first element of 'Safety_Stocks', use `Reduce` to get the sum of the corresponding `list` elements and assign (`:=`) the output to a new column ('New_SafetyStocks').

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, New_SafetyStocks := Reduce(`+`, shift(Sales_Forecast, 
           type="lead", n=seq(Safety_Stocks[1L]))) , by = Product]
df1
#      Product Sales_Forecast Safety_Stocks New_SafetyStocks
# 1: Product A            100             2              300
# 2: Product A            100             2              300
# 3: Product A            200             2              400
# 4: Product A            100             2              600
# 5: Product A            300             2              400
# 6: Product A            300             2              200
# 7: Product A            100             2              300
# 8: Product A            100             2              500
# 9: Product A            200             2              400
#10: Product A            300             2              200
#11: Product A            100             2               NA
#12: Product A            100             2               NA
#13: Product B            500             3             2000
#14: Product B            500             3             3000
#15: Product B           1000             3             3500
#16: Product B            500             3             3500
#17: Product B           1500             3             2500
#18: Product B           1500             3             2000
#19: Product B            500             3             3000
#20: Product B            500             3             3000
#21: Product B           1000             3             2500
#22: Product B           1500             3               NA
#23: Product B            500             3               NA
#24: Product B            500             3               NA
```

<

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Product = rep(c("Product A", "Product B"), each = 12),
       Sales_Forecast = c(100, 100, 200, 100, 300, 300, 100, 100, 200, 300,
    100, 100, 500, 500, 1000, 500, 1500, 1500, 500, 500, 1000, 1500, 500, 500),
   Safety_Stocks = rep(c(2,3), each = 12))
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun! I get the error messages below: > library(data.table)
Error in library(data.table) : there is no package called ‘data.table’
> setDT(df1)[, New_SafetyStocks := Reduce(`+`, shift(Sales_Forecast, 
+            type="lead", n=seq(Safety_Stocks[1L]))) , by = Product]
Error: could not find function "setDT" . Would you know why?

Comment: @Nico Seems like you didn't install the package, Try `install.packages("data.table"); library(data.table)` and the code